# PHP replace CSS in HTML tags

Tags: php, css

does anyone has an idea about replace css styles into style attribute on html tags
example you have css file, html file

css:

> #example { color: #CCC; font-weight: bold; }

html:

> <div id="example">Example</div>

and you will have this when you run php

> <div style="color: #CCC; font-weight: bold;">Example</div>

***why oh why :)***
some work need inline styles for some system  that doesn't support <link>, <style> or script tags
example:
E-mail template (all of you can not insert <link>, <style>, <script> inside the email right ?),
or build HTML for insert in another system (product detail in amazon.com, ...)

Comment: if you have styles like .class1 .class2 { ... } class2 { .. }, it will be not easy to replace into HTML tags

Comment: the great thing about css is keeping the style separate, why do you want to reverse that?

Comment: hunting bats in daylight is far more useful than what you want to do.

Comment: a little context would be useful here. Having a separate stylesheet is preferable to inline styles. Update your question explaining why you want to do this. There is perhaps a different solution to your problem.

Comment: seperate styles from html is great but some work need that, example: email template or create html for another system that don't allow to insert style, link or script tag

Comment: sure I build email templates all the time, different code base\file I don't see the value in scripting a conversion between the 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use a DOM parser, take a look at [SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Here's an example:

```
// Assuming that it's an array of styles
// keyed by HTML element IDs or classes.
// @see http://www.google.com/search?q=php+css+parser
$styles = some_php_css_parser('example.css');

// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();

// Load HTML from a HTML file, 
// there are also other options, @see API.
$html->load_file('test.htm');

// Walk through the target elements.
foreach ($html->find('blah') as $element) {
    $element->style = $styles[$element->id];
}

// Cache and output...
```

Also you **need** to consider caching the output, otherwise I also say so, *but why oh why!*

Answer (score 0):

explode the css file, extract the attribute\css, str_replace the attribute with the css in the html, but why oh why.

Comment: glob() is my favourite based on name.